# .epub e-book can't be read in Apple Books

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, epub

I have an .epub e-book that was created in 2018. It was tested and worked with Kindle, Apple, and several other readers.

Now, the file does not work in Apple books - and multiple people have tested or complained about this.

I updated the file to make some corrections, and I still experience the error.

The exact error is: "Book Content Unavailable. There was a problem loading book content. Try closing and reopening the book or relaunching the device." (This does nothing.)

But I can take the exact same file and open it in Kindle, Nook app, and two other e-readers I downloaded from the AppStore. They read it without incident.

I created the book in Calibre and ran both the Calibre bug check and the ePubcheck plugin. No errors found.

I have no idea what the problem is, and why it is just Apple. Has anyone else encountered this? Any ideas or guesses?

Searches for similar problems from others yielded only user-related questions.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Apple Books (corresponding to at least iOS v16.1) has a bug that has rendered certain eBooks unreadable. This seems to persist between iPad OS and iOS.

I have experienced this specifically with ePub format books created from Google Docs. One poor workaround I have found is using Pages to create the ePub version of the file - this version works, though, is without headers.

I suspect several bugs exist in the "updated" version of Books. You could try creating the ePub with a different program.

Would love if anyone has found a fix for this.